# Как записать строку с пробелами в файл Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если указываю так

`inf.writelines([str(first), str(second), str(third)])`

То записывается всё без пробелов. Как решить?

Comment: `.write(f'{str(first)} {str(second)} {str(third)}')`

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
inf.writelines(" ".join(map(str, [first, second, third])))
```